# Generate positive random numbers with fixed mean and SD

Tags: r, matlab, random

How can I generate a positive random number list with specified mean and SD?
I know how to do it with rnorm in R but it is not positive since it sampled from a normal distribution, if I'm right.

My preferred language is matlab but a script in R is Ok too.
thanks.

Comment: I think it really depends on what mean, sd and distribution you are after. You can do rpois, runif, r... whatever.

Comment: Well, I want to generate different list's of numbers with sd=0 to sd=500 so I can check an equation behavior on different data lists.

Comment: sd=0 is just a constant. For sd = 500 you have to pick one of the distributions. rpois(n, lambda = 500) will give you n numbers from poisson distribution with mean 500 and sd = 500. For uniform distribution, you could do a uniform with length 1732.051 to get a standard deviation of 500.

Comment: Ups.. I messed up the sd and variance in the poisson case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on the underlying distribution.

With `R = normrnd(mu,sigma)` you can generate normal distributed random numbers with specified mean and standard deviation.

`R = lognrnd(mu,sigma)` generates lognormal distributed random numbers.

You can also take a look at [this](https://de.mathworks.com/help/stats/random.html) where you can specify the distribution.

Just make sure that you check if it really is positive, e.g.

```
mu = 10;
sigma = 1;
R = normrnd(mu,sigma,1,500); 
   %R(R<=0) = resample
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it does what I want also it has negative numbers but it is not so frequent like the function in R. One more think for anyone who wants to use it, the mean and sd is not exact.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not shure, but maby this function helps you:

```
function Y=rand_std(mean,SD)
    while 1==1
        X=rand*2*mean;
        Y=rand;
        if Y<1/(SD*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-(X-mean)^2/(2*SD^2))
            return;
        end
    end 
end
```